# data parse with json touch

Tags: php, iphone, json

I am using this example: http://tempered.mobi/sites/default/files/JSonArticle.zip

But it show null value at time parsing.

My PHP code output:

```
{"news":[{"title":"DurianFM Android Application"},{"title":"Hari Raya"},{"title":"C"}]}
```

iPhone code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...........jsontest.php"];
  NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

  NSLog(jsonreturn); // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are

  NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
  NSError *error = nil;

  // In "real" code you should surround this with try and catch
  NSDictionary * dict = [[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error] retain];
  if (dict)
  {
    rows = [dict objectForKey:@"news"];
  }

  NSLog(@"Array: %@",rows);


  [jsonreturn release];
}
```

when I check **dict variable** it always show null value .
it's a big problem for me .
         **NSData not convert into NSDictionary 
          NSDictionary variable show null value.**

please help .

**I have solved this problem by change deserializeAsDictionary to deserialize**

Comment: change url with any of json string file or webservice.It may help u

Answer (score 0):

you have to change tag.

```
rows = [dict objectForKey:@"news"];
```

**EDIT**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...........jsontest.php"];
NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *results = [jsonreturn JSONValue];
```

Try this one it works for me.

Comment: thanx for reply , I have changed users to news but it not work .
when I check dict variable it always show null value .
it's a big problem for me .
         NSData not convert into NSDictionary 
          NSDictionary variable show null value.

please help .